# horizontal scrollView scroll automatically after some seconds

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal `scrollView` which contains 2 images.The `scrollView` is circular.What I want to do is to set automatic scroll after a few seconds.Any idea how could I do that?

I tried the following:

```
[UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:5];
    [UIScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
```

but this: `[UIScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];` is not recognized.Any idea?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Something like this :-)

```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

     - (void) onTimer {

       // Updates the variable h, adding 100 (put your own value here!)
      h += 100; 

      //This makes the scrollView scroll to the desired position  
      yourScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, h);  

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you've misunderstood the animation declaration syntax
let's suggest, you have your scroll view referenced as following in your code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = ...; // it must have a reference to the actual scroll view instance
...
[UIView beginAnimations: @"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 5.0f];

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x,y)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

this should work for you